# phpunit and mock for many depended objects

Tags: mocking, phpunit, fixtures, stub

I'm just trying to understand what is the "right way" to write unit tests in following case:

```
class Time
{
    public function __construct(Hour $h, Minute $m, Second $s) {}
}

class TimeRange
{
    public function __construct(Time $start, Time, $end)
    {
        if ($this->startTime > $this->endTime) {
            throw new \Exception;
        }
    }
}
```

The aim is, to implement unit test for the TimeRange constructor method, which will help make sure that exception is throwing at some point

How to properly get Mock of the Time object in that case (without getting mock spaghetti) ?

Comment: Looks like your Time class is just a value object, most likely it's immutable. Don't mock value objects, just create them.

Comment: @JakubZalas Yep you are right, and this is what I did previously, but now I met the problem, If logic of the value object going to be changed, then all your test will be ruined. In opinion it makes very complicated maintaining such code. With Mock/Stub objects it's could be easier

Comment: Value objects don't have complex logic. They're values.

Comment: some invariants may be complex enough, but you are right it make sense to  keep them as simple as possible. Well, Imagine that TimeRange should represent slice of the day from 2am to 2am next day - which is represent business day essentially. Then shown invariant won't be so simple anymore.

Comment: By stubbing it you might put it in an invalid state (invariants won't be protected).

Comment: http://www.mockobjects.com/2007/04/test-smell-everything-is-mocked.html

Answer (score 0):

Mock creation can become quite complex. In the production code, complex tasks are handled by specialized classes or modules. In this case it's the same. You can and should abstract the stubs and mocks creation in classes. Those classes should be part of the testing suite.

In your case for example. you could have a class that will return a `Time` object initialized with a certain hour, minute, second:

```
<?php

class FixtureFactory
{
    public function getNewTimeMock($hour, $minute, $second)
    {
        // code for creating the mock
    }
}
```

Here is a link to XUnit Design patterns book on the relevant section. There are lots of patterns just for creating mocks:

http://xunitpatterns.com/Fixture%20Setup%20Patterns.html

Comment: thanks for the link, what do you think using mocks vs real objects, like  Jakub Zalas suggested above ?

Comment: I agree. Whenever possible use real objects. If there is no need don't make things more complex. But when mocks or stubs must be used the mock creation is not trivial it's useful having some helper class creating them so the test code does not get bloated and there is no repetition.

Comment: But if I would use real objects it means it's an integration test more than unit, right ?

Comment: If the real objects don't access database, network, or whatever system resource, I would not consider the test an integration one just because all the dependencies are not mocked. For example you are creating the `Time` object with a controlled time. If you used the system time for creating it then it probably would not be a unit test because it could possibly fail at some times but not at others.

Comment: @user1016265 I only said don't mock value objects. Mock almost any other collaborators.